# Testing that an algorithm has converged

Tags: numerics, algorithm

It's frequent that when writing some kind of algorithm (numerical integration, clustering, whathaveyou) I'll want to say "Stop the algorithm and return the result when some error $\epsilon$ is below some threshold $\delta$."

For example, I might write a numerical integrator which will estimate the area under $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by applying the trapezoid rule on increasingly finer grained partitions of $[a,b]$ and returning the finest-grained approximation when the difference between the area of this approximation and the previous one (call it $\epsilon$) is smaller than some pre-defined precision $\delta$.

What is the best way to write such a program in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all of these algorithms can be described in the following form:

Assume your iterative numerical algorithm `f` takes and returns a pair `{x, additionalState}`. `x` is the quantity (tensor) that should converge, while the `additionalState` describes the current problem (e.g. the objective function, the function to be integrated, the points to be clustered) and keeps track of things learned in previous iterations. For instance, for numerical integration, `additionalState` would keep track of where the function has been evaluated so far. For Nelder–Mead non-linear simplex algorithm/search, it would contain the the `n+1` vertices of the simplex, for clustering the current cluster associations etc.

You define `initializeF[...]` which gives the initial guess for the quantity `x` and builds the `additionalState` for the algorithm.

Then the following meta-algorithm will return the first result of iterated application of `f` where `x` differs by less than `delta` from the previous `x` in the norm:

#### Procedural Implementation

```
runUntilConvergenceP[f_, initializeF_, delta_, args___] := 
  Module[{xstate},
   xstate = initializeF@args;

   While[
    Norm[
      xstate[[1]] - (xstate = f@xstate)[[1]] (*note: 
      relies on expressions being evaluated left-to-right*)
      ] >= delta
    , Null (*VOID*)];

   xstate
   ];
```

#### Functional Implementation

(prefer this)

```
runUntilConvergenceF[f_, initializeF_, delta_, args___] := 
  NestWhile[f, initializeF@args, Norm[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] >= delta &, 
   2];
```

or if you want to preserve intermediate results:

```
runUntilConvergenceFList[f_, initializeF_, delta_, args___] := 
  NestWhileList[f, initializeF@args, 
   Norm[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] >= delta &, 2];
```

## Examples

### k-Means Clustering

```
assignToClosest[clusterCenters_List, points_List] := 
 With[{nf = Nearest@clusterCenters},
  GroupBy[points, First@*nf]~AssociationMap~clusterCenters(*GroupBy + 
  preserve the order of clusterCenters*)
  ]

(*objective to minimize*)
kmeansTotalError[clusters_] := KeyValueMap[
   Function[{center, points}, Norm[# - center] & /@ points // Total]
   , clusters
   ] // Total

kmeansStepSub[clusterCenters_List, points_List] := 
  With[{clusters = assignToClosest[clusterCenters, points]}
   , {kmeansTotalError@clusters, {points, clusters}}
   ];

kmeansInitialize[{k_Integer?Positive, points_List}] /; 
   Length@points >= k := 
  With[{clusterCenters = RandomSample[points, k]}
   , kmeansStepSub[clusterCenters, points]
   ];

ClearAll@kmeansStep
kmeansStep[{totalError_, {points_, clusters_}}] := 
 With[{clusterCenters = Mean /@ Values@clusters}
  , kmeansStepSub[clusterCenters, points]
  ]

showKMeansState@{totalError_, {points_, clusters_}} := Show@{
    ListPlot[Values@clusters, PlotMarkers -> "o"](*,
    Graphics@{PointSize@Large,Red,Point[Keys@clusters]}*)
    , ListPlot[List /@ Keys@clusters, PlotStyle -> PointSize@Large]
    , VoronoiMesh[Keys@clusters, , 
     PlotTheme -> "Lines"](*VoronoiMesh used to visualize the cluster-
    association policy*)
    }~Labeled~totalError
```

Example with 1000 points in the unit box and 10 (initially random) cluster centers:

```
$data = RandomReal[1., {1000, 2}];
(*multiple runs on the same data may give different results with the \
randomized k-means algorithm - you may want to optimize here as well*)


run[] := showKMeansState /@ runUntilConvergenceFList[
   kmeansStep, kmeansInitialize, 10.^-3, {10, $data}
   ]

run[] // ListAnimate
Export["animation.gif", 
 Rasterize /@ run[],(*AnimationRepetitions\[Rule]Infinity*)
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> \[Infinity]]
run[] // ListAnimate
```

[image: k-means clustering in Mathematica]

(aah, I love animated simulations)

### Newton's Method

```
newtonsMethodStep[{x_,(*additionalState*){h_, epsilon_}}] := 
 With[{dhx = (h[x + epsilon] - h@x)/epsilon},

  {
   x - h@x/dhx(*xn+1 = xn - h(xn)/h'(xn)*)
   ,(*additionalState does not change here*){h, epsilon}
   }
  ]

newtonsMethodInitialize[{x0_, h_, epsilon_}] := {x0, {h, epsilon}};
```

Finding a zero of `Sin` around 2 to $10^{-10}$ accuracy:

```
(1. Pi)~NumberForm~10

runUntilConvergenceP[
  newtonsMethodStep, newtonsMethodInitialize, 
  10.^-10, {2., Sin, 10.^-6}
  ]~NumberForm~10

runUntilConvergenceF[
  newtonsMethodStep, newtonsMethodInitialize, 
  10.^-10, {2., Sin, 10.^-6}
  ]~NumberForm~10
```

Output

```
3.141592654
{3.141592654,{Sin,1.*10^(-6)}}
{3.141592654,{Sin,1.*10^(-6)}}
```

### Numerical Integration with Trapezoids

```
trapezoidArea@{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}} := (x1 - x0)*Mean@{y0, y1};

trapezoidIntegrationStepSub@{h_, 
    supports_} := {trapezoidArea /@ Partition[supports, 2, 1] // 
    Total, {h, supports}};

trapezoidIntegrationInitialize[{h_, xs_List}] := 
  With[{supports = {#, h@#} & /@ xs},
   trapezoidIntegrationStepSub@{h, supports}
   ];

trapezoidIntegrationStep@{_, {h_, supports_List}} := With[{
    newSupports = ({#1, 
          With[{x = Mean[First /@ {##}]}, {x, h@x}], #2} & @@@ 
        Partition[supports, 2, 1])~Level~{-2}
    }
   , trapezoidIntegrationStepSub@{h, newSupports}
   ];
```

Integration of sine from 0 to 1:

```
NIntegrate[Sin@x, {x, 0, 1}]~NumberForm~8

runUntilConvergenceF[
   trapezoidIntegrationStep, trapezoidIntegrationInitialize, 
   10.^-8, {Sin, Range[0., 1., 0.1]}
   ][[1]]~NumberForm~8
```

Output:

```
0.45969769
0.45969769
```

---

Full notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8QfIyUuQqvbXZocndFWkJNVEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Implementation with `FixedPoint`: ``runUntilConvergenceF2[f_, initializeF_, delta_, args___] := 
  FixedPoint[f, initializeF@args, 
   SameTest -> (Norm[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < delta &)];``

Comment: Thank you; this is an excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

For `NIntegrate`, use `AccuracyGoal`:

```
NIntegrate[10^(-5)/(1 + 10^2 (x - 1/2)^2), 
{x, 0, 1}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

Each such function has a similar option, which can be easily read from the function documentation.  Termination goals for clustering are fundamentally different from numerical integration, to take just one example.

If you write your own function, the implementation will depend upon exactly how you implement that function, and hence cannot have a definitive answer here.

Comment: This does not answer the question in the generality it was asked.

Comment: Well, that's because what you do in one case won't necessarily work for another, @Diff. I actually think the current question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: (e.g. I might use `NestWhile[]`/`FixedPoint[]` in one case, and `Do[]` or `While[]` in another. Those call for different ways to implement a termination criterion.